# Can you read a dynamodb managed backup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If I create a backup using [CreateBackup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateBackup.html) or [UpdateContinuousBackups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateContinuousBackups.html) can I read the backup without restoring the table? I'd like to read from s3 or another source.

I don't want to use Glue or Data Pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to access the data in a DynamoDB backup is to use [`RestoreTableFromBackup()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreTableFromBackup.html), which **creates a new table from an existing backup**.